# Why MouseLeave event is fired even if mouse point is placed on the element?

Tags: wpf

I have a canvas with a button and a border:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="canvas1" >
        <Button  Name="button1" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="6" Name="border1" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Now what I want is on mouseenter of the border1, button1 should be visible and border itself should be hidden. And on mouseleave vice-versa. So written following handlers for two events:

```
void border1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    border1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    button1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

void border1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    border1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    button1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

The problem is MouseLeave is firing even if I put the mouse pointer on the border itself. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try a Background="Transparent" on the border, but I think the big issue is that you're hiding the border. I would think when you hide it you would get a MouseLeave event because your mouse is no longer in it since it's not there any more.

Answer (score 1):

hmm, i tried your code, and it works for me.
But let me just say that is' fundamentally very wrong.

first of all, we usually don't do these events on the border, since it's normally a thin element, and you can miss the event if you move your mouse too fast and in general you have to be accurate on it.
it's better to do the event on whatever is inside the border.

second of all, how is the MouseLeave method supposed to be called if mouse enter makes the border hidden?!
it doesn't appear anymore!

it would make more sense if clicking the button would make the border appear again.
try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="canvas1" >
        <Button Width="100" Content="button" Height="100" Name="button1" Visibility="Hidden" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="6" Name="border1" Canvas.Left="194" Canvas.Top="22" Height="78" Width="111" MouseEnter="border1_MouseEnter" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>

void border1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        border1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        button1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        border1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        button1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```